# How to add only the 2nd elements from tuples in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

how do I add only the 2nd elements from list of tuples in Python? For example:

```
tuples_list = [(0, 10), (0, 20), (0, 30)]
```

How to add `9` to only the 2nd elements in tuples_list to get the following?

```
tuples_list = [(0, 19), (0, 29), (0, 39)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `tuple` is immutable, create new tuples with list comprehension:

```
tuples_list = [(0, 10), (0, 20), (0, 30)]
[(i, j+9, *k) for i, j, *k in tuples_list]
```

Output:

```
[(0, 19), (0, 29), (0, 39)]
```

Note that I've added `*k` to ensure the loop doesn't break with tuples with more than 2 elements

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
res = [(i[0],i[1]+9) for i in tuples_list]
print(res)
```

Output:-

```
[(0, 19), (0, 29), (0, 39)]
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying different things with the code myself, I managed to chance upon a quick solution using numpy:

```
import numpy as np 

tuples_list = [(0, 10), (0, 20), (0, 30)]

tuples_add = np.array(tuples_list) + (0, 9)

tuples_add
array([[ 0, 19], [ 0, 29], [ 0, 39]])
```

Hope this helps